# Set data fields on the document / template, for all users to see as Read-only

Tags: docusignapi

I have a Word document that serves as the Document template. It only has an outline on it. I then added text fields to the template.

for example, the template JSON, it looks like this:

```
"recipients": 
{ ...
   "signers": [
   { ...
       "tabs": 
       {
            "listTabs": [
              {
                 "documentId": "1",
                 "pageNumber": "1",
                 "recipientId": "55177519",
                 "tabType": "list",
                 "tabLabel": "##parentf2e8b853-3ef1-4872-af19-4f1e3c60a3a7##recipient",
                 "listItems": [
                    {
                       "text": "Dealer",
                       "value": "Dealer"
                    },
                    {
                       "text": "Customer",
                       "value": "Customer"
                    }
                 ],
                 "required": "true",
                 "shared": "true",
                 "value": ""
              }
           ],
           "textTabs": [
              {
                 "documentId": "1",
                 "height": "19",
                 "pageNumber": "1",
                 "recipientId": "55177519",
                 "tabId": "55ab5a10-54d6-4ca0-a66b-7c637c8ad61a",
                 ...
                 "tabLabel": "DealerPhone",
                 ...
              },
```

My questions are:

1. How can I get all of the text fields to display the data, no matter who the recipient is- for example, the **DealerPhone** above? Under "Collaboration", I have set the fields set to "Recipients can Collaborate".
2. Once the first user selects the user from the drop-down list (the **listTab** below), I do not want subsequent users to go in and change that selection, but I **do** need the users to see who the previous / first user selected in that drop-down list.

I can share JSON files of both the template and what I'm sending to create the envelope. The template displays, but the text data is blank.

Sample JSON request body:

```
    {
    "email": "...email....",
    "name": "Test Dealer",
    "roleName": "Dealer",
    "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
        {
            "tabLabel": "DealerPhone",
            "value": "1-800-111-2222"
        },
        {
            "tabLabel": "DealerContact",
            "value": "Billy Dealer"
        }]
    }
}],
   "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - TEST!!!",
   "templateId": "{{templateId}}",   
   "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an account-level setting that's relevant here, available from Go to Admin > Sending Settings > **When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients**. With that enabled, all pre-populated data will be visible to all recipients. With that disabled, data only gets 'burned in' to the PDF when the assigned recipient completes their role.

If you do not want later recipients to be able to change the value of the dropdown, you will want to disable Collaboration on it. Later signers will be able to see that selection regardless of if Collaboration is enabled or not.

Finally, you'll want to avoid using Conditional Logic on fields that should always appear. Setting a tag to be a conditional child means that it will only appear if circumstances are met.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I tried that, and the data still is not showing - is that because the tabs are defined under specific signers?

Is there a way to set the tabs / data to be generic, and not under the signers? Or maybe I have the tabs and **tabLabels** not set properly?

Can I just match based on **tabLabel**, or do I  need to match on the **tabId** of the **textTabs**?

Comment: You can match on TabLabel alone, without the tabId. Tags must be assigned to a specific signer, and the assignment in the template JSON must match the assignment in the API call - so if a tag is assigned to the Signer1 role in a template, the API request must have a TemplateRoles section that references Signer1 and has that TextTab object under it.

Answer (score 1):

If recipients sign sequentially (increasing routing order) then every subsequent recipient can see the tabs that prior recipients have filled and they cannot modify them. If you have all tabs assigned to your first recipient, all the other recipients will see them but they'll be read-only for them.